# Demo Telnet Session

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, telnet

I'm currently working on a project for my university. We wrote a CLI application and want to present it now. what I would like to habe is the current workflow:

```
telnet 123.123.123.123
session connects with ANY username
our program starts user can interact with it
application exits or quits
user gets disconnected from the session
```

I searched now for quite a while but haven't found anything in the internet.
I wouldn't mind if it is ssh either.

I have tried to put the command into the .bashrc but then the session doesn't end with program termination. I also found the command parameter for the keys file in ssh but the I would have to know the keys.

Thanks in advance

PS.: The Server is a Ubuntu 12.04 Maschine

Comment: Can you show your `.bashrc` file ?

Comment: it just contains ./path/to/myProgram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i've found a Solution. I just wrote a little node application that acts as a telnet Server and behaves exactly like I want. If anybody needs it: I've uploaded it to my github: https://github.com/dangrie158/TelnetDemoServer/

Comment: Accept your answer if it fits for you. It will help other users.